# I am having issues debugging multiple C files using vscode. The configuration I have right now seems to only work for 1 C file

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Is there a way I can change it to allow for multiple files to be debugged? Whenever I try running multiple files I get a pop up saying "The prelaunchTask C/C++: gcc build active file terminated with exit code 1". Also in the terminal there is a message saying

/.vscode/tasks.json: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
/.vscode/tasks.json:1: syntax error
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Build finished with error(s).
The terminal process failed to launch (exit code: -1).

Here is a picture of my tasks.json file
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEKpx.png